# file_get_contents después de redirección 302

Tags: php

Necesito scrapear el contenido de una url de una empresa de mensajería nacional, para marcar mis envíos como entregados.

Antes con la url *https://www.xxxxxxx.es/seguimiento_envios/xxxx_historico_nacional.asp?envio=123456789* me devolvía una página correcta, pero se ve que tuvieron problemas de seguridad y ahora cuando pasas la consulta te devuelve el resultado en una página genérica siempre, sin el código de envío que se ve al final, de la forma: https://www.xxxxxxxxx.es/seguimiento_envios/xxxxx_historico_nacional.asp?modo=nacional.

Con lo que al hacer el file_get_contents de la que lleva el código del envío me devuelve un error 302.

¿Cómo podría obtener el contendido de esa redirección para scrapearlo y ver si se ha entregado o no el envío?.

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Muchas gracias @masterguru, viendo tu respuesta he preparado esto aunque no esta bien, ¿Qué tendría que cambiar?

```
$fields = [ 
  
'xxx-finder-follow-code-two' => '011...........7' 

]; 

$postdata = http_build_query($fields); 

$ch = curl_init() 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.xxx.es/seguimiento_envios/validar_seguiment.asp'); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

var_dump $result;
```

Comment: Lo tienes mal para que podamos ayudarte bien... deberias decirnos el dominio para verlo insitu, pero si lo haces entonces ellos tambien lo sabran y buscaran otro modo de protegerse. Lo suyo es que te ofrezcan una API donde poder realizar esas consultas acotadas a tu negocio, con una clave seguramente o algo parecido. Pregúntales a ellos como hacerlo, también les interesa si eres cliente suyo. Por otra parte, ese error es típico. Hace años también descubrí una vulnerabilidad en una empresa de transportes nacional que les pasaba lo mismo, y cualquiera podia sacar sus albaranes con datos sensible

Comment: @masterguru , muchas gracias, eso fué lo que les pasó estas pasadas navidades, e intuía lo que me comentas, que me deberían facilitar algún token o api para hacer la consulta identificando a mi empresa. He probado con CURL, etc y no consigo nada.

Comment: He investigado y ya veo que empresa es... Viendo su formulario ahora debes enviar la petición a `/seguimiento_envios/validar_seguiment.asp` con CURL y mandarles un POST del campo `xxx-finder-follow-code-two` donde `xxx` ya sabes lo que representa (en minusculas)... eso te deberia devolver esta página con la informacion del envio: `https://www.xxx.es/seguimiento_envios/xxx_resultados_consultas.asp?modo=nacional` y al darle al botón `CONSULTAR` te mandaria a la página `https://www.xxx.es/seguimiento_envios/xxx_historico_nacional.asp?fecha=nnnn-nn-nn&tr=n`. Pero directamente no va. Usan cookies.

Comment: Es extraño que no te permitan acceder a esa info desde una API. Si tuvieron problemas de seguridad, lo propio es que hayan implementado un sistema de autenticación, usando API Keys o de otro modo. Te recomendaría que te pongas en contacto con ellos exponiéndoles el problema.

Comment: Si, pero eso tan solo te podria servir para recoger la cookie, pues la pagina real tan solo te muestra un poco de texto y el botón que te interesa ejecutar despues (CONSULTAR)... una vez recogida la cookie quizas puedas usarla para ir a la página final de mi anterior comentario y finalmente sacar los datos que deseas

Comment: Puff, se me escapa, no sabría hacerlo, hablaré con ellos a ver qué solución me dan. Muchas gracias de corazón @masterguru y a A. Cedano también por su comentario.

Comment: Eso de las cookies se hace con cURL tambien ([ejemplo de como capturarlas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895858/10382744) y [ejemplo de como usarlas despues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885587/10382744)... quizas lo consigas si analizas bien ese codigo y lo adaptas a tu escenario

Comment: que version de php es?

Comment: La versión del php es la 7.0.33.